# Rotating keys and reactive reencypt data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-kms

I want to introduce key rotation to my system but for that reencryption is needed. It would be nice to do it reactively on some event, trigger etc., but I can't find anything like that at google documentation.

After a rotate event, I want to reencrypt data with the new key and destroy the old one.

Any ideas, how to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you rotate an encryption key (or when you enable scheduled rotation on a key), Cloud KMS does not automatically delete the old key version material. You can still decrypt data previously encrypted with the old key unless you manually disable/destroy that key version. You can read more about this in detail in the [Cloud KMS Key rotation documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/key-rotation).

While you may have business requirements, it's not a Cloud KMS requirement that you re-encrypt old data with the new key version material.

- New data will be encrypted with the new key
- Old data will be decrypted with the old key

At the time of this writing, Cloud KMS does not publish an event when a key is rotated. If you have a business requirement to re-encrypt all existing data with the new key, you could do one of the following:

### Use Cloud Scheduler

Write a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) connected to [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/) that invokes on a periodic basis. For example, if your keys rotate every 72 hours, you could schedule the cloud function to run every 24 hours. Happy to provide some sample code if that would help, but the OP didn't specifically ask for code.

### Long-poll

Write a long-running function that polls the KMS API to check if the Primary crypto key has changed, and trigger your re-encryption when change is detected.

Comment: You can use StackDriver logging (filter) to trigger an event on key rotation (CreateCryptoKeyVersion).

Comment: The schedule is the best option I think. Reacting on logs entries is too tricky for me.

Answer (score 3):

As of right now, the best that you can do is write something that polls GetCryptoKey on regular intervals, checks to see if the primary version has changed, and then decrypts and reencrypts if it has.

We definitely understand the desire for eventing based on key lifecycle changes, and we've been thinking about the best way to accomplish that in the future.  We don't have any plans to share yet, though.